# Limit app to just kindle-fire and/or Nook Tablet?

Tags: kindle-fire

I'm new to android development but I've almost completely ported my iOS game SkyWords to android.. specifically targeting the Kindle-Fire.  I have bought the device to test with and my app works ok. I've tried my app running on some of the other emulators with various screen sizes and my app isn't really working well.  Can I release my app and just target devices with the 1024x600 screen res only (fire and nook).  If so how do I submit and app that way? I wouldn't want phone users to pay to download my app and get upset because it's not formatted to work. 
Thanks

Daniel

Comment: you can try to find your answer here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html - specifically, <supports-screens>

Answer (score 0):

When submitted an app to the Amazon appstore (the only legit way to get an app on to the kindle fire), you will be given an option to pick the form factor. Your choices will be phone, phone+tablet or tablet. You should pick "tablet".

Answer (score 0):

Submit to the NOOK Storefront and it will only be availble to NOOK devices. http://nookdeveloper.com for more information.

Tom